# Saving a timestamp value from a given string value in java

Tags: java, datetime

I am having a string value in format "2013-11-19 07:41:38.990000000". I want this value to be converted into a timestamp field in "19-NOV-13 07.41.38.000000000 AM" format in my oracle database.

I have tried to convert it using the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(faxRecd);
timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

But while inserting it is generating the following error:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Maybe it's in the US style, that month is on the end?

Comment: i have tried with various DateFormat, each one is generating certain errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the date format on each database to ensuer they are the same
Code:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters
```

Comment: "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM" is NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.
Is there any idea to solve the above issue?